# UserControl Namespace Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am having a problem with my user control. I am getting a parser error: "Could not load type 'AsMyDotComSite.UserControls.GoogleAnalyticUC'." I think it is a problem with my namespace, but I am not sure can anyone help me out?

My ascx user control file:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="MyDotComSite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GoogleAnalyticUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="AsMyDotComSite.UserControls.GoogleAnalyticUC"%>

<!-- Google Analytics -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  //GOOGLE CODE HERE
</script>
```

My code behind:

```
namespace AsMyDotComSite.UserControls
{
    public partial class GoogleAnalyticUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncludeGoogleAnalytics"] == "true" &&
    (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.Edit &&
     SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.New);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the assemblies you've registered in the directive? Have you tried moving the assemblies below the control in the page directive?

Comment: I register it using `<%@ Register TagPrefix="Google" TagName ="GoogleAnalyltics" Src="~/_controltemplates/MyDotComSite/GoogleAnalylticUC.ascx" %>` and ive tried first, and last and neither work. The file does exist on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just a typo? You have `CodeBehind="GoogleAnalyticUC.ascx.cs"`, but you say you register it using `Src="~/_controltemplates/MyDotComSite/GoogleAnalylticUC.ascx"` (an extra "l" in "Analytic"). Unless you tweaked those file names by hand, that would explain the error - the files are `GoogleAnalylticUC.ascx` and `GoogleAnalylticUC.ascx.cs`, but you try to use nonexistent `GoogleAnalyticUC.ascx.cs` as code behind.

Comment: Ohh Sorry that was my typo, I was hand typing couldn't copy and paste because its on a different machine. Thanks Though.